# JQM wait until all elements has been created

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Is there a way in `jquery mobile` to wait until all elements has been created from my db result?

1 - A `click()` fire's `$.mobile.changePage("somePage.html");`

2 - I made a  `$("body").on("pageinit", "#id-from-page", function(){ loadMyStuffs(); })` to start mounting my stuffs from `database`

3 - the `loadMyStuffs();` create some elements using `append();` from my `db result`.

basicly , work in this three steps, but the problem is that the page show's before the elements has been created.

So, how can i make a `4 step` with something like `showpagenow` ?

the loop its something like this:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= imgNum; i++ ){
    // stats from step

    var imageList = "<li class='img-steps'>"+
                        "<img class='view-step' src='"+ base_url + "/" + data.result[i].IMGPAT + data.result[i].IMGNAM + "'/>"+
                    "</li>";

    // append to ul list image
    $(".img-ul").append(imageList);
}
```

any tips, be my guest.

Answer (score 1):

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements and they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on(). The document element is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready.

Try to use `$(document).on("pageinit", "#id-of-page", function()`

You may check the below example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
        <title>Cars example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).on( "pageinit", "#car-details-page", function( e ) {
                var listItems = '';
                for (var i=0; i<50; i++) {
                    listItems += ["<li><a href=\"#\" id=\"acura\">Acura_",i,"</a></li>"].join("");
                }
                $("#car-list").append(listItems).listview("refresh");
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="car-page" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1><a data-ajax="false" href="/">Car list</a></h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">   
                <a href="#car-details-page">Go to Page 2</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="car-details-page" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1><a data-ajax="false" href="/">Car details</a></h1>
                <a data-rel="back">Back</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">   
                <ul data-role="listview" id="car-list">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps.